# Searching meaning of a word under cursor in Emacs using `dict` utility

Tags: emacs

Hi I am currently reading some novels in `.txt` format downloaded from Gutenberg. 
Often I come across a word I am unfamiliar with, and I need to look it up on the web.

I recently stumbled upon the Unix `dict` command-line utility to search for meanings of words. It fetches
the meanings of words from multiples dictionaries and thesauruses on the web.

I would like to have this integrated with Emacs in the following way.

I would like to pass the word under the cursor to the `dict` and split the window into two buffers
: one buffer containing the current text-file and another-one the meaning of the words.

How would I write an Emacs-Lisp function for doing this?

NOTE: Using dict at the command-line is as simple as `dict *word-being-searched*`
      and I am using Emacs-24 under Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: not an answer. But I have a small plugin for sdcv. Do you want to modify it for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `word-at-point` function does most of the work you need:

```
(require 'thingatpt)

(defun lookup-word-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (format "dict %s" (shell-quote-argument (word-at-point)))))
```

Like any other invocation of `shell-command`, this will show the output of `dict` in the minibuffer if it's short enough; otherwise, it will pop up a window named `*Shell Command Output*`.

Answer (score -1):

`ispell` is your friend. `ispell-word`, bound by default to `M-$` does exactly that.

Also see [wordnet.el](http://xwl.appspot.com/ref/wordnet.el)

EDIT: As Thomas pointed out, ispell is not appropriate. I am a big fan of wordnet that I mentioned earlier, you will need to [download](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) the program.

Another option is an interface to the dict command, e.g. [enter link description here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DictMode) or one of the alternatives listed on that page.

There is enough stuff out there that you don't need to write something on your own.

Comment: The OP is not looking for spelling correction, but for a thesaurus lookup.

Comment: oops :) `wordnet` should help though